# arpspoof Delay Time between replies

Tags: arp-spoofing

"arpspoof" arp replies every second and I think about what is a reasonable time to send arp replies without affecting the network performance, or just making arpspoof not so noticiable.

Is there any arpspoof config to change that? I guess in "ettercap" is possible in /etc/etter.conf

Comment: Looking through the dsniff package, there does not seem to be a way to change the rate at which broadcasts are sent.